# String formating with Python's escape sequence

Tags: python, string, escaping, hex, sequence

For clarification purposes, I am rewriting from scratch with additional information.

Consider the following:

```
y = hex(1200)
y
'0x4b0'
```

I need to replace that first 0 of y with a '\' to make it look like '\x04b0'. I am communicating with an instrument over [RS-232](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RS-232) serial which takes parameters strictly in that format ('\xSumCharsHere'). Python won't let me do the following.

```
z = '\x' + y[2:]
ValueError: invalid \x escape
```

The following is not acceptable, because it still has '\\' in the actual value assigned to z.

```
z = '\\' + y[1:]
z
'\\x4b0'
```

The end goal is to send a command like this to my serial port:

```
s.write(z) # s is a serial object
s.write('\x04b0') # This call is an equivalent of the call above
s.write('\\x04b0') # This command will not work
```

Comment: What is your actual aim?  You start with a number, and you want the three-character string `"\x04b0"` as a result?  I don't think this is what you really want.

Comment: The actual aim is to obtain the result in this format '\x<someNumGoesHere>'. I am communicating with an instrument over Rs232 serial and it takes comands strictly in that format above.

Comment: It's still not clear what you mean.  The Python string `"\x04b0"` consists of the characters `"\x04"`, `"b"` and `"0"`.  How many characters is the string you want supposed to have?

Comment: Here is my overall aim:
I pass degree angles in hex format to a Goto command. Like the example above, x = hex(1200) where 1200 is the angle in degrees. It does not matter how many characters I have in x. All that matters is that i have the angle format i described above (like '\x04b0', it could be '\x11' for some different angle)

Comment: @Aasam Tasaddaq: See edit of my answer.

Comment: "I am communicating with an instrument over RS-232 serial which takes parameters strictly in that format ('\xSumCharsHere')." No, it doesn't. There are *serious* fundamental misunderstandings in play here, and it's impossible to answer the question because there's no proper place to start.

Answer (score 2):

Your last bit of code doesn't do what you think it does:

```
>>> x = hex(1200)
>>> y = '\\' + x[1: len(x)]
>>> y
'\\x4b0'
>>> print y
\x4b0
```

When you type the name of a variable in the Python console, Python prints the string's *representation as Python code*, which is why you see two backslashes -- a literal backslash in a Python string is escaped by another leading backslash.  This code does in fact work, the representation of the result is just throwing you off.

However, I would suggest you use this snippet instead, since yours is omitting leading zeroes:

```
>>> y = '\\x%04x' % 1200
>>> print y
\x04b0
```

Answer (score 1):

Your last code bit is correct, and it can be alternatively written using a raw string:

```
y = r'\x' + x[2: len(x)]
```

As cdhowie said in his answer:

> When you type the name of a variable in the Python console, Python prints the string's representation as Python code. This code does in fact work, the representation of the result is just throwing you off.

This is an alternative for hand-writing escape sequences, however, and one I think is slightly better coding practice as it is much more readable.

Answer (score 0):

The latter will work. In the console, Python uses `repr()` to print objects, which in this case will show the double slash. Do `print y` in the console and you'll see that it outputs properly.

You can also clean up your first example a bit:

```
y = "\\x" + x[2:]
```

Or the second:

```
y = "\\" + x[1:]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to get the string `\0x4b0` as the representation at the console, you need to actually call `print` on it at the console:

```
>>> s='\\0{}'.format(hex(1200)[1:])
>>> s
'\\0x4b0'
>>> print s
\0x4b0
>>> s2='\\0'+hex(1200)[1:]
>>> s2
'\\0x4b0'
>>> print s2
\0x4b0
```

If you just FORM the string in the console (i.e., it does not go through `print`), Python is showing you its representation:

```
>>> '\\0{}'.format(hex(1200)[1:])
'\\0x4b0'
>>> repr(s2)
"'\\\\0x4b0'"
>>> s2
'\\0x4b0'
```

**Edit (based on your comment):**

I assume this is an old HP plotter?

Don't be confused by what the shell is showing as your string.

You state that you want to produce a string of `\x<someNumGoesHere>` (or is it `\x0<someNumGoesHere>` with a leading `0`?)

Here is how:

```
>>> def angle_string(angle):
...    return '\\0{}'.format(hex(angle)[1:])
... 
>>> angle_string(1200)
'\\x04b0'
>>> print _
\x04b0
>>> angle_string(33)
'\\x021'
>>> print _
\x021
```

When you send the string to your device (through the OS file/print like service to the RS232 port), it will be as you format it.

**Edit 2**

String interpolation is the process where these [string literals](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/ref/strings.html):

```
>>> s1
'\n\n\t\tline'
```

Get translated to this:

```
>>> print s


       line
```

Logically, these literal characters are single characters:

```
>>> s1[0]
'\n'
>>> len('\\')
1
```

My guess is that the way you have opened the serial port `s` is using the strings is raw mode, so the string `\\x0123` is being sent that way (raw mode) vs being interpreted as `\x0123`

You might try as a work around this:

```
>>> cmd=chr(92)+'0'+hex(1200)[1:]
>>> s.write(cmd)
```

I think you also need to open the serial port in [FileLike](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/pyserial_api.html#serial.FileLike) mode so that the string literals are sent as proper single characters.

Comment: Its a lunar photomoeter with a very strange implementation. it is still returning a value with '\\' which does not work.

Comment: @Aasam Tasaddaq: How did you open the file `s`?

Comment: s is a serial object for port communication. heres my initialization for s
import serial
s = serial.Serial(2)
s.sendBreak()
s.write('\x11') # '\x11' is a different scenario im using here for the purpose of an example. 

This works fine.

Comment: @Aasam Tasaddaq: I think your issue is that the serial interface is not correctly converting `\\x` into `\x`. Try opening the serial interface `s` in text mode?

Comment: Sorry, i misunderstood your question. I was using s in my python shell. I think that is what you were asking.

Comment: @Aasam Tasaddaq: Through PySerial? There are two ways you can open a serial interface: raw and FileLike. Use FileLike and the `\\x` will become `\x` in translation. An alternative is to write to a tmp file and read it back and then send to the serial. My guess is that you have opened the serial IO in a way that the strings sent are not being properly interpolated.

Comment: Yes I am using PySerial. I am relatively new to python and programming. I suppose i am openning it in raw mode (?). I will take a look at FileLike mode now which I dont know about. Thank you for your help!

Comment: quick question: what exactly is the difference between the two. Or can you please point me towards some online source for clarification.